# Object DataSource and Grid View (NestedGrid)

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

i have a method that results a Class object that hold (properties + list)

after adding ObjectSource in webform i associated Object Datasource with Grid view. its selecting values and showing in Grid but problem is GridView is not showing values that are in List

i have tried to add Template field and then put another Grid to hold all values that is in List but it didnt worked

can some one help me out ??? how i can achieve this .

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Features">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                           DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SerialNo"  >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label id="pubid_lbl" Runat="Server" Text='<%# Eval("SerialNo") %>'/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Can you put all the grid view HTML ?!

Comment: Please post your code behind code.